# Interface that implements all it realizations

Tags: c#, interface

I have interface:

```
public interface IPettable
{
   void Pet();
}
```

I have two classes that implement this interface:

```
public class Cat : IPettable
{
   public void Pet()
   {
      ...
   }
}

public class Dog : IPettable
{
   public void Pet()
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

I want third IPettable interface to be able two call both of this realizations. How to do it?

```
public class PetAllAnimals : IPettable
{
   public void Pet()
   {
       dog.Pet();
       cat.Pet();
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to create a Cat and a Dog first.

Comment: Yeah, ofcource, but what is the way of it creation, should i inject two of those interfaces in constructor of PetAllAnimals for example?

Comment: You first need to create the concrete objects, then you can put them in some kind of container lets say List<IPettable> which allows you to use them in a generic manner.

Comment: I think you answered your own question: yes, you could build an array/list/IEnumerable of all the IPettable instances you want to Pet, and pass it into your PetAllAnimals class somehow.  A constructor for PetAllAnimals is one way, or else you can add some other method to add or update the IPettables.  Note that the class name is misleading in that case - the class would really be PetADefinedGroupOfAnimals, not _all_ possible instances of IPettable.

Comment: In general, a class should be a noun... `Dog` and `Cat` are fine, but `PetAllAnimals` is a verb. Seems like that should be a method, not a class. Can you describe what you're trying to do, from a higher level? Do you intend to create a `AnimalCollection`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all classes that implement `IPettable` interface and call `Pet()` method.
like this

```
public class PetAllAnimals : IPettable
{
   public void Pet()
   {
        var ipettableType = typeof(IPettable);
        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(a => !a.IsInterface &&
            ipettableType.IsAssignableFrom(a) &&
            a.GetTypeInfo() != typeof(PetAllAnimals).GetTypeInfo());

        foreach (var item in types)
        {
            IPettable instance = (IPettable)Activator.CreateInstance(item);
            instance.Pet();
        }
   }
}
```

Another way is creating an instance of `Cat` and `Dog` class ,then initialize fields in `constructor` and call `Pet()` method

```
public class PetAllAnimals : IPettable
{
   private readonly IPettable dog;
   private readonly IPettable cat;
   public PetAllAnimals()
   {
       cat = new Cat();
       dog = new Dog();
   }
   public void Pet()
   {
       dog.Pet();
       cat.Pet();
   }
}
```